# Implement imageView swipe in UITableView with horizontal scrolling and page indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview

I would like to have a tableview cell with a swipeable imageview, as given in the example below :-

[image]

I have gone through the UIPageView elements but I cannot figure out how to implement it in a tableView Cell?

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize your UITableCell.
For that you have to add:

- SwipeView for image display
   You can follow this link:
  https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView
- UIPageControl
  You can track page number from swipeview's numberOfPages and currentPage property.
- Any other Detail View
  Which Contains your product detail,
  favorite or any other buttons or labels.

Comment: Hi is there a swift version of the SwipeView ? Or can someone direct me to a custom scroll view?

Comment: You can go through these [link1](https://github.com/jeffbarg/SwipeView) ,[link2](https://github.com/lbrendanl/SwiftSwipeView)